# start canvas animation on collision and ease it to stop

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I was working on learning animations through the canvas when I ran into a bit of a problem, with the help of a little jQuery I've created two rectangles on my canvas. One that originates at the center of the canvas and one that is controlled by my mouse location. What id like to do is when the mouse rectangle hits the second one on the canvas. I would like the second rectangle to move in the direction it was hit from.

The problem I've been running into is that I would like the animation to be fluid and ease to a nice stop.  Below in the code Iv'e got the second square automatically performing the way id like the animation to look when its been struck, but when I put it in an if colliding is true statement the second square only moves 5px. Now this makes sense to me because it is only told to move 5 pixels if the boxes are touching and I've even tried running a for loop within the if statement to run a certain number of times and slowly decrement the velocity as it reaches the length I want it to move. This however just causes the 2nd box to jump to the end and not show an animation.  Sorry for the longwinded question, but if anyone could point me in the right direction or tell me how I can refactor the code to make this work Id appreciate it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 400;
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var particles = [];

var mouseSize = 50;
var isColliding = false;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

function particle() {
  var particle = {
    originX: width / 2,
    originY: height / 2,
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2,
    movement: 60, //overall movement wanted when collides
    velocity: 5,
    size: 30,
    draw: function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size)


      this.x += this.velocity;
      this.velocity *= .98;

    }
  }
  return particle;
}

function createParticles() {

  particles.push(particle())
}

createParticles();

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  //console.log(event.pageX+','+event.pageY)
  //mouse rect created here. did not create directly in mouseMove event because I could not
  //properly clear the canvas between each frame and keep all objects on screen.
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, mouseSize, mouseSize);

  particles[0].draw();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(event) {
  console.log(isColliding);
  mouseX = event.pageX;
  mouseY = event.pageY;

  //if objects are colliding set iscolliding to true, otherwise set it to false;
  if(event.pageX < particles[0].x + particles[0].size &&
    event.pageX + mouseSize > particles[0].x &&
    event.pageY < particles[0].y + particles[0].size &&
    mouseSize + event.pageY > particles[0].y) {
    isColliding = true;
    // console.log("collison detected");    
  } 
  else{isColliding=false;}

})

window.onload = draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? I added some variables (oldMouseX, oldMouseY) to keep track of the mouse's previous coordinates and that way its direction could be calculated. Then your particle also needs X and Y velocities to allow it to move on both those axis... assuming you want that. If you don't want changes in Y then never mind. But it looks like your smooth stopping action works for me. I am not sure if I understand what you want exactly. I also added a reset variable so that it wouldn't keep implementing the collusion until the boxes separated again.

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:black">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 400;
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var particles = [];

var mouseSize = 50;
var isColliding = false;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
var oldMouseX;
var oldMouseY;
var reset = true;

function particle() {
    var particle = {
    originX: width / 2,
    originY: height / 2,
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2,
    movement: 60,
    velocityX: 0,
    velocityY: 0,
    size: 30,
    draw: function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size)


      this.x += this.velocityX;
      this.y += this.velocityY;
      this.velocityX *= .98;
      this.velocityY *= .98;

    }
  }
  return particle;
}

function createParticles() {

  particles.push(particle())
}

createParticles();

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  //console.log(event.pageX+','+event.pageY)
  //mouse rect created here. did not create directly in mouseMove event because i could not
  //properly clear the canvas between each frame and keep all objects on screen.
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, mouseSize, mouseSize);

  particles[0].draw();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  console.log(isColliding);
  oldMouseX = mouseX;
  oldMouseY = mouseY;
  mouseX = event.pageX;
  mouseY = event.pageY;

  //if objects are colliding set iscolliding to true, otherwise set it to false;
  if(event.pageX < particles[0].x + particles[0].size &&
    event.pageX + mouseSize > particles[0].x &&
    event.pageY < particles[0].y + particles[0].size &&
    mouseSize + event.pageY > particles[0].y) {
    isColliding = true;
    // console.log("collison detected");
  } 
  else{isColliding=false; reset=true;}

  if (isColliding && reset) {
    particles[0].velocityX = mouseX - oldMouseX;
    particles[0].velocityY = mouseY - oldMouseY;
    reset = false;
    }


})

window.onload = draw();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh sorry i should probably be more specific. the square that i want to move currently moves automatically and eases to a stop regardless of wether or not there is any collision. What I am looking for is how to make that animation fully implement after a collision is detected, and than later on will add additional code to take into account direction of collision.

Comment: It moves automatically because you gave it a velocity of 5 when you created the particle. If you want it to happen after a collusion then just set its velocity to 5 after a collusion is detected. By the way I edited my answer to implement the reset variable and fix the direction so it is more natural now.

Comment: such an easy solution to a question that had me scatchin my head super hard. I could kiss you right now lol. thank you.

Comment: No problem, I love making things like that on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

### **Ease functions**

You can use a ease function, of which there are many.

Ease function take a value from 0 to 1 and return a modified value from 0-1. The difference between the input value and the return represents the ease.

The following image shows an example of a slightly more complex ease function that takes a second value called p (or power) that modifies the curve that the function creates. It shows 3 values for p with the value 1 producing a linear response. Pow can be any value from 0 < p < Infinity x is the input and y is the output.

[image]

<sub>*Sorry dont have image editor on hand so function is not the one used in example*</sub>

**Basic polynomial ease function**

The most basic ease function (of any use that is) is the polynomial (simply means a function that has something to a power). The input value is clamped and the output is the value to the power of p.

```
function easeInOut(v,p){  // p < 1 is rush out ease in , 
                          //  p > 1 is ease out rush in
                          // p = 1 and the function is linear
    v = v < 0 ? 0 : v > 1 ? 1 : v;  // clamp input also clamps output
    return Math.pow(v,p); // return value
}
```

**Using an ease function**

To use an ease function you need the two positions you want to ease a objects position between

```
var fromX = 10;
var fromY = 10;
var toX = 100;
var toY = 100;
```

Then get the difference between them

```
var dx = toX - fromX;
var dy = toY - fromY;
```

Then use the ease function to get an modified unit distance

```
var uDist = 0.5; // half way along
var uDistE = easeInOut(moveD,0.2);

// the position eased
var x = fromX + dx * uDistE;
var y = fromY + dy * uDistE;
```

**Ease over time**

You do this over time with the value `uDist` changing from 0 at the start to 1 at the end. If you wish that to be a fixed time then you record the start time and the time to move and normalise it.

```
var startTime = performance.now(); // do this when you start movement


const timeToMove = 2000; // time to move in ms (2000 = 2 seconds)

var uDist = (performance.now()-startTime) / timeToMove; // ease function clamps 
                                                        // values so no need
                                                        // to worry about being 
                                                       // out of range
```

**Demo using Ease function**

The example shows the use of ease function to move particles. In the demo there are 4 types of movement each has a different power for the ease function. Smaller circles have rush out ease in  and large particles are ease out rush in.

Half the code is boilerplate, the stuff related to the answer is at the top.

Best viewed full page.

```js
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
// Note set window.onResize (note capital R) to get the debounced resize call
// ie onResize = function(){ // blah blah };
// Note. mouse, canvas, ctx are set for you. Mouse is a simple mouse with
// x,y,w (wheel) alt,shift,ctrl, and buttonRaw as a bit field bits 0,1,2 for buttons left, mid, right
// ie if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1) { //is left button down (othe buttons may be down also
// ie if(mouse.buttonRaw === 1) { //is only left button down
// set debounced resize event function to put new particles on canvas
onResize = function(){ particles.length = 0; };
const pSize = 5; // particle size (radius)
var particles = []; // array of things
const mouseSize = 30; // Size of mouse (radius)
const mouseCol = "red"; // guess what this holds???
const runDist = 300; // How far a particl will move when touched
const moveSpeed = 0.01; // speed to move (will move 1 unit dist so 1 / MoveSpeed == number frames to move)
const edgeDist = 10; // distance particles will stay away from the canvas edge.
const MAX_PARTICLES = 200; // the max number oof you know whats

// ease function return unit value clamped from 0-1 based on the input value clamped 0-1
// most functions take a second argument that is a curve modifier. Usualy the power
const EASE_FUNC = {
    linear : function (val) {
        val = val < 0 ? 0 : val > 1 ? 1 : val;
        return val;
    },
    easePow : function (val, pow) { // for pow > 1 this is ease out rush in
        // for pow > 0 & pow < 1 this is rush out ease in
        val = val < 0 ? 0 : val > 1 ? 1 : val;
        return Math.pow(val, pow);
    },
}
const particleMoveFunction = EASE_FUNC.easePow; // ease function to use


// creates a particle at x,y
function createParticle(x, y) {
    var typesC = "#F80,#8F0,#0D0,#00F".split(",");
    var curves = [0.2,0.5,1.2,2];
    var sizes = [1,1.2,1.6,2.2];
    var type = Math.floor(4-Math.sqrt(Math.random() * 16)); // more small fast
    
    return {
        x : x,
        y : y,
        lx : x,
        ly : y,
        dest : {
            x : x,
            y : y,
        },
        from : {
            x : x,
            y : y,
        },
        size : pSize * sizes[type],
        col : typesC[type] ,
        moveTime : 0,
        moveSpeed : moveSpeed,
        moveCurve : curves[type],
    }
}

// Move particles.
// checks for mouse interaction
// checks for edge distance
// moves particles is particle moveTime > 0
function updateAllParticles() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        var p = particles[i];
        p.lx = p.x;
        p.ly = p.y;
        if (p.moveTime > 0) {
            p.moveTime -= p.moveSpeed;
            var pos = particleMoveFunction(1 - p.moveTime, p.moveCurve);
            p.x = (p.dest.x - p.from.x) * pos + p.from.x;
            p.y = (p.dest.y - p.from.y) * pos + p.from.y;
        }
        p.x = p.x < p.size + edgeDist ? p.size + edgeDist : (p.x >= canvas.width - p.size - edgeDist ? canvas.width - p.size - edgeDist : p.x);
        p.y = p.y < p.size + edgeDist ? p.size + edgeDist : (p.y >= canvas.height - p.size - edgeDist ? canvas.height - p.size - edgeDist : p.y);

        var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouse.x - p.x, 2) + Math.pow(mouse.y - p.y, 2));
        if (dist < mouseSize + p.size) {
            var dx = (p.x - mouse.x) / dist;
            var dy = (p.y - mouse.y) / dist;
            p.x = mouse.x + dx * (mouseSize + p.size); // move to edge of mouse
            p.y = mouse.y + dy * (mouseSize + p.size);
            // random is to stop them grouping to much
            var rd = runDist / 2 + Math.random() * runDist / 2;
            p.dest.x = p.x + dx * rd + Math.random() * 5 - 2.5;
            p.dest.y = p.y + dy * rd + Math.random() * 5 - 2.5;
            p.from.x = p.x;
            p.from.y = p.y;
            p.moveTime = 1;
        }
        p.distMoved = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.lx - p.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.ly - p.y, 2));
    }
}

// draw particles
function drawAllParticles() {
    var i;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        var p = particles[i];
        ctx.strokeStyle = p.col;
        ctx.lineWidth = p.size * 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.lx, p.ly);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

// draws the mouse object
function drawMouse() {
    ctx.fillStyle = mouseCol;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mouse.x + mouseSize, mouse.y);
    ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, mouseSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}

// Main display function
function display() {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.33; // fade background
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);


    ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
    if (particles.length < MAX_PARTICLES) {
        particles.push(createParticle(
                Math.random() * (canvas.width - pSize * 2) + pSize,
                Math.random() * (canvas.height - pSize * 2) + pSize));
    }
    updateAllParticles();
    drawAllParticles();
    drawMouse();
}

//==================================================================================================
// Boilerplate code not part of answer
//
//
// The following code is support code that provides me with a standard interface to various forums.
// It provides a mouse interface, a full screen canvas, and some global often used variable
// like canvas, ctx, mouse, w, h (width and height), globalTime
// This code is not intended to be part of the answer unless specified and has been formated to reduce
// display size. It should not be used as an example of how to write a canvas interface.
// By Blindman67
if (typeof onResize === "undefined") {
    window["onResize"] = undefined; // create without the JS parser knowing it exists.
    // this allows for it to be declared in an outside
    // modal.
}
const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
var w, h, cw, ch, canvas, ctx, mouse, createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals, globalTime = 0, resizeCount = 0;
createCanvas = function () {
    var c,
    cs;
    cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style;
    cs.position = "absolute";
    cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
    cs.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    return c;
}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === undefined) {
        canvas = createCanvas();
    }
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") {
        setGlobals();
    }
    if (typeof onResize === "function") {
        resizeCount += 1;
        setTimeout(debounceResize, RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);
    }
}
function debounceResize() {
    resizeCount -= 1;
    if (resizeCount <= 0) {
        onResize();
    }
}
setGlobals = function () {
    cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2;
    mouse.updateBounds();
}
mouse = (function () {
    function preventDefault(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        w : 0,
        alt : false,
        shift : false,
        ctrl : false,
        buttonRaw : 0,
        over : false,
        bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3],
        active : false,
        bounds : null,
        mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.clientX - m.bounds.left;
        m.y = e.clientY - m.bounds.top;
        m.alt = e.altKey;
        m.shift = e.shiftKey;
        m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") {
            m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which - 1];
        } else if (t === "mouseup") {
            m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
        } else if (t === "mouseout") {
            m.buttonRaw = 0;
            m.over = false;
        } else if (t === "mouseover") {
            m.over = true;
        } else if (t === "mousewheel") {
            m.w = e.wheelDelta;
        } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") {
            m.w = -e.detail;
        }
        if (m.callbacks) {
            m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e));
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.updateBounds = function () {
        if (m.active) {
            m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === undefined) {
                m.callbacks = [callback];
            } else {
                m.callbacks.push(callback);
            }
        } else {
            throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function");
        }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== undefined) {
            m.removeMouse();
        }
        m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === undefined ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
            m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);
        });
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) {
            m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false);
        }
        m.active = true;
        m.updateBounds();
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== undefined) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
                m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove);
            });
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) {
                m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);
            }
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = undefined;
            m.active = false;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();
resizeCanvas();
mouse.start(canvas, true);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
function update(timer) { // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display(); // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```